# CSS Coin flip animation

Tags: html, css

So I want to create a coin flip animation, what I tried is:

```css
@import "compass";

body {
    background-color: #edebc4;
}
h1 {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.flip-container {
    position: absolute;
    perspective: 1000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    @include transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    &:hover .flipper, 
    &.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    &, 
    .front, 
    .back {
        @include border-radius(100px);
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    /* flip speed goes here */
    .flipper {
        transition: 0.6s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative;
        /* hide back of pane during swap */
        .front, .back {
            backface-visibility: hidden;

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        /* front pane, placed above back */
        .front {
            z-index: 2;
            /* for firefox 31 */
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
        /* back, initially hidden pane */
        .back {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
    }/*.flipper*/
}/*.flip-container*/
```

```html
<h1>Coin flip</h1>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/100/100/1" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/100/100/2" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason it doesn't work on my server or jsfiddle. What's more interesting, it actually does work on codepen - http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/jPdjmm

Example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r0xpoqmn/

What can be reason of that?

Comment: See Compass being imported and SCSS being used,,,check that first. You can't just cut and paste without understanding the basic principles.

Comment: In JSFiddle, you can change your CSS panel to work with SCSS. This example works. I changed the image urls and remove the import in your CSS -> https://jsfiddle.net/r0xpoqmn/2/

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use :hover in css? using javascript for this is really not necessary and you will need to use a polyfill since ie9 doesn't support classList.toggle

Comment: Updated to include mixins: https://jsfiddle.net/5gy0k8rz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pen style is `SCSS`. Click on 'compile to `CSS`' and copy the compiled code. Of course, you also need to correct your image paths so switch `//` for `http://`

> SCSS is one of the syntaxes of SASS, which is a CSS preprocessor that improves the possibilities on your style code, with features like 'nesting' and 'variables'.

working version: [**link**](https://jsfiddle.net/8f4L8eqo/)

Comment: You can choose SCSS as your stylesheet option in JSFiddle. Here is the code with prepossessed SCSS: https://jsfiddle.net/r0xpoqmn/3/ Don't just tell OP to compile the code and paste it. Help them understand what SCSS and SASS are.

Comment: Agreed the answer is missing SCSS info but I believe that jsfiddle wasnt his main problem, the worst part is that it also didnt work on his server;

Answer (score 1):

Your server doesn't have compass installed, if you remove compass and update the images src to use http:// instead of // you will see that it semi-works.

To fix, install compass on your server http://compass-style.org/

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your JSFiddle example does not work is because a new *Fiddle* defaults to CSS. Since the provided stylesheet is written using a CSS preprocessor language, you need to set the CSS panel to interpret SCSS.

Click on the gear at the top-right of the panel and select "SCSS" as the language then paste the SCSS code from the Code Pen.

#### Almost There...

To get this to work now, you will need to do one of the following:

- Remove the `@import "compass";` line and include the missing mixins. (See demo).

  or
- Fix the import and add the correct path to a CDN or local file.

---

<kbd>[**`╔═══════════════╗`

`║ JSFiddle Demo ║`

`╚═══════════════╝`**](https://jsfiddle.net/5gy0k8rz/)</kbd>